# Regular expression for Scrapy rules

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I want to crawl data from pages with format: `http://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels?page=i` where `i` is from `0` to some integer.

Is the following regex correct for this pattern:

```
start_urls = [
        "http://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels"
    ]

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"com/vessels\?page=[1-100]"),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 1-100 range, you can use

```
r"com/vessels\?page=(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)\b"
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY6lJ4/1)

In case you need any number, just use `\d+`:

```
r"com/vessels\?page=\d+"
```

See [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/vY6lJ4/2)

Comment: why there is `\b` a the end of that one. Generally, the number will go from 0 to about 50000.

Comment: To match any numbers, just use `\d+`. Or `[0-9]+`.

Comment: In case I just want the number to go from 0 - 50000, is it correct to write `\?page=[0-50000]`. Thank you very much for your patient to help me

Comment: No, ranges in regex cannot be set with `[]`, this way you create a character class, meaning *any character inside it*. You need `\b(?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-4][0-9]{4}|50000)\b` to match numbers from 0 to 50000. `\b` means *word boundary*.